# JQuery blinking image in cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the blinking image. There is a jquery code:

```
function blink(){
        $("#light_3_1").animate({"opacity": 0}, 400 ).animate({"opacity": 1}, 400 );
    }   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(blink, 500);
    });
```

I want to make delay effect(10 seconds of blinking, then stop for some time, then again blinking and again stop...), but i can't find the way how to do it.

Comment: Hi Eldar, just posted a simple solution to solve your problem, if you will like to try CSS animations just let me know and I can create a sample for you... is way much better than trying to animate with javascript, since the GPU takes care of your css animations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard you like intervals, so let's get an interval to control your interval so you can run an interval while you run an interval.

The following **live demo** has a "blink interval" running at 500ms, and a "pause interval" that controls the blink interval, running at 2000ms:

```js
function blink() {
    $("#light_3_1").animate({
        "opacity": 0
    }, 400).animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 400);
}

var blinkInterval;
var pauseInterval;
var blinking = true;

$(document).ready(function () {
    blinkInterval = setInterval(blink, 500);
    pauseInterval = setInterval(toggleBlink, 2000);
});

function toggleBlink() {
    if (blinking) {
        clearInterval(blinkInterval);
        blinking = false;
    } else {
        blinkInterval = setInterval(blink, 500);
        blinking = true;
    }
}
```

```css
#light_3_1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="light_3_1"></div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/kv18e1sL/1/

Comment: Thank You so much. You've resolved my problem. Respect for your amazing skill :)

Comment: Hello. I have a new question: I've done that image blinking slow, then it has pause, then it blinks fast. But then it does not repeat all cycle, it continues blink fast with pauses.
So can i do this way, as example? (slow blinking - pause - fast blinking - pause .........and repeat all cycle from slow blinking)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to stop after 10segs(10,000 ms) you just need to increment a variable to turn off the SetInterval.

**Here I made a sample for you:**
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/t83tb683/

*However you should use `CSS animation` that way your animations are not going to impact your javascript thread.*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var counter = 0;

    function blink(){
       $("#light_3_1").animate({"opacity": 0}, 400 ).animate({"opacity": 1}, 400 );
        counter++;
        if(counter > 9) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }   
     var interval = setInterval(blink, 500);
});
```

---

**Here is a version with CSS (RECOMMENDED):** http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/t83tb683/1/

Comment: Thank You for your answer. It's an interesting way.

Comment: There is a version with `CSS Animations instead` Good look with your project man! :)